# Rails create table from csv that has special character in column name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a CSV file that i'm trying to load to rails database. Everything works fine until it gets to a column named `BW (MB)`. I'm thinking it's an issue with the parentheses as the other headers have spaces and they are fine. I'd like to avoid renaming the header in the original CSV file itself if possible.

Code:

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file, :headers => true) do |row|
    Sevonedatum.create!(row.to_hash.slice('Date', 'Market Area', 'BW (MB)'))
end
```

Error output:

> ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors: 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment ["96.26"] to BW  (undefined method `BW =' for #)]

You can see the `MultiparameterAssignment` error is pointing to an issue when the value is being assigned to `BW`, though in the error it's missing the `(MB)` portion.

From the migration file:

```
class CreateSevonedata < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :sevonedata do |t|

t.column :'Date', :date
t.column :'Market Area', :string
t.column :'BW (MB)', :float
t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: What's the definition of your Sevonedatum class?

Comment: Hi John. I added in the code that created the Sevonedatum class/table. In mysql database, I have a table called sevonedata. Sorry if i misunderstood your question i'm fairly new to rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have parentheses in a column name: Rails will try to map the column name "BW (MB)" to a valid Ruby attribute name, and parentheses aren't allowed.  Spaces convert to underlines OK, but parentheses aren't allowed.

Look at how Active Record does [convention over configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record) - one of the key principles of Rails.

Rails lets you do some amount of overriding, but you can't have a column "BW (MB)" that equates to a valid Ruby class attribute.

You have 2 options - both of which you need to change the column name to "BW".

Option 1: edit the headers of the CSV files so they match the column name, and change your code accordingly.

Option 2: leave the header as-is, but write additional code to replace the hash key "BW (MB)" with "BW"

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file, :headers => true) do |row|
  foo = row.to_hash.slice('Date', 'Market Area', 'BW (MB)')
  foo["BW"] = foo["BW (MB)"]
  foo.delete("BW (MB)")
  Sevonedatum.create!(foo)
end
```

(you can optimize that to fewer lines - I'm making it verbose since you've said you're a beginner)

Comment: Thanks John. I ended up going with the first method to keep a consistent convention.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the header_converters to convert the headers by utilizing :symbol to convert everything to downcase and remove everything except numbers, letters, and add underscore between spaces. I then modified my database column names to match.

```
CSV.foreach(csv_file, :headers => true, :header_converters => [:symbol] ) do |row|
Sevonedatum.create!(row.to_hash.slice('market_area', 'date', 'interface', 'peak_period_downlink_util', 'bw_mb'))
    end
```